# nextjs ISR with cloudfront

Tags: next.js, amazon-cloudfront, vercel

Our website, written with nextjs, currently has mix of Static pages, Server sider rendered pages and dynamic pages too. Due to increased build times, we are planning to move away from static generation and use ISR instead.

I wanted to understand how ISR should be configured on AWS Cloudfront?

We need a mechanism to update the cloudfront cache whenever certain paths are updated. As I understand Vercel takes care of this automatically. Any suggestion on how to manage this on AWS?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Having the same issue trying to work out how best to do it.

Comment: Update: nextjs now allows you to access low level cache API - which can be used to have shared cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Vercel

Going straight to the point: Cloudfront itself does not contain all the moving parts required for ISR. The closest you can get from that is the use of `stale-while-revalidate`, but it appears Cloudfront does not support it yet. Perhaps the [Serverless Framework](https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js#features) is a better candidate since they support Incremental Static Regeneration with the use of SQS and Lambda ([PR link](https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js/pull/1028)). As of now, the Serverless framework does not support [On-Demand ISR](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-1#on-demand-incremental-static-regeneration-beta) since it is a brand-new feature.

EDIT (2023-05-18): Cloudfront now supports `stale-while-revalidate`. Thanks @cristian for the contribution. Do notice `stale-while-revalidate` does not work in the same way as ISR.

*Disclaimer: I work for Vercel*

Comment: Maybe we can achieve On-Demand ISR by invalidating cloudfront cache on demand. I will try this one.

Comment: The problem there is propagation and how to ensure you are "pushing" the latest version. Not as simple as it looks.

Comment: Looks like even after 6 months the support for on-demand ISR isn't there on AWS along with middlewares. And as of `stale-while-revalidate`, looks like AWS cloudfront team has no plans to support it. Unfortunately, many people can't use vercel for many reaons one being orgs depending only on 1 cloud provider.

Comment: @EternalObserver I would love to chat more about the reason for not using Vercel. We always gather feedback from users when they are open to discuss them. So send me a message at paulo@vercel.com so I can connect with the team that works on that area if you want.

Comment: The main reason we won’t use Vercel is the pricing.

Comment: CloudFront now supports `stale-while-revalidate` - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/05/amazon-cloudfront-stale-while-revalidate-stale-if-error-cache-control-directives/

Comment: ISR != SWR. Watch out for this gotcha.

Comment: Added an edit @Cristian

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I could come up with is to invalidate CloudFront's cache manually along side next's cache. I abstracted all of the revalidation logic into one function:

```
  // root = path matcher passed to CloudWatch
  // paths = array of paths passed to nextjs revalidate
  // example: revalidatePaths('/blog/*', ['blog/article-a', 'blog/article-b'])

  async function revalidatePaths(root, paths) {
    if (paths) {
      await Promise.all(paths.map((path) => revalidate(path)));
    } else {
      await revalidate(root);
    }

    try {
      await cf
        .createInvalidation({
          DistributionId: process.env.CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID,
          InvalidationBatch: {
            CallerReference: `${new Date().getMilliseconds()}-${Math.random()}`,
            Paths: {
              Quantity: 1,
              Items: [root],
            },
          },
        })
        .promise();
      console.log('SUCCESSFULLY INVALIDATED');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
```

There is a slight delay when invalidating CloudFront's cache compared to a platform like Vercel, but overall this works pretty well.